# Why do I get Error: Cannot find module 'html' when running nodejs express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I'm trying to create a server for my HTML application, but when I go to localhost:8080/map I get `Error: Cannot find module 'HTML'`. Still, the main at localhost:8080 page works fine.

My code :

```
const path = require('path');
const port = 8080;
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set("view engine", html);


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.html')
})

app.get('/map/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('map.html')
})

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${server.address().port}/`)
 })
```

Comment: You wrote html without quotes, so your script just doesn't recognize what html is.
app.set("view engine", "html");

Comment: There's not point to rendering HTML files, just use `res.sendFile('public/index.html')`

Answer (score -1):

You are using EJS so you need to do this

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
```

Use the `app.engine(ext, callback)` method to create your own template engine. `ext` refers to the file extension, and `callback` is the template engine function, which accepts the following items as parameters: the location of the file, the options object, and the callback function.

So with that you actually make the node runtime to load the 'html' template engine and it works fine.

Please refer to this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-app-engine-function/)

Also you are missing quotes on this line `app.set("view engine", html);`. It should be `app.set("view engine", "html");`